# Rewrite urls inside subdirectory with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a wordpress installation inside a subdirectory called "wordpresss"

Inside that directory i have a .htaccess file

I am trying to rewrite a file inside the root of the wordpress directory like this

http://mysite.com/wordpress/facebook.php?i=135

into

http://mysite.com/wordpress/facebook/135.html

This is what i have so far and i cant seem to work out what is wrong...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^facebook/([0-9]+)\.html$ facebook.php?i=$2
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: What did you do, what happened and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: My expectation is that when i call the url i can view the page the same way as http://mysite.com/wordpress/facebook.php?i=135 but while typing http://mysite.com/wordpress/facebook/135.html. For the moment i only get the 404 errer - file not found

Comment: To debug this you could add the [R] option to the end of RewriteRule. This will redirect the browser to the rewritten URL so you can easily see what Apache tries to load as a result of that rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables prepended by a dollar sign in a RewriteRule uses info from the parts between brackets. Since you only have one of those ( `([0-9]+)` ) you only have one variable to work with. Change the `$2` to `$1` and see if that works.